# Comparing two llvm:SmallPtrSet for equality

Tags: llvm

I trying to rewrite some `std::set` usages to [llvm::SmallPtrSet](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#llvm-adt-smallptrset-h) (fast set implementation based on small vector and iterating the vector for every operation). Almost everything works, but the problem is with `operator==` - I can compare two `std::set` objects and can't compare SmallPtrSet object.

How can I compare two `SmallPtrSet`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SmallPtrSet`'s methods like `count()`, `erase()`, ... compare objects by their memory address, not via equality defined in some overloaded `==` operator.

If you need to check for *equals* instead of *is same*, I suggest you write a small helper that iterates over the sets and checks your equality constraints.

Comment: Yes, I want to compare, if the elements, stored in the set are same. Elements may be pushed in different order, so I need the helper.